# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting the above mentioned exception while executing the SQL query in Java.

```
statement2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO visit_header" 
    + "VALUES('"+visitnumber+"','"+date+"','"+cookie+"','"+ip+"')");
```

I want to know where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per initial look, you have a problem in your sql query:

```
statement2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO visit_header" + "VALUES
```

Should be

```
statement2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO visit_header " + "VALUES  //Note space after header
```

There was no space between visit_header and VALUES, so your query was like this:

```
INSERT INTO visit_headerVALUES
```

Which is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now, but now i am getting the exception below java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'EXAMPLE'

Comment: @user2314206, can you login to example table using sql-plus? does user really have privileges to access that tablespace?

Comment: Ok. I have given the privileges. I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to put space between visit_header and values:

```
statement2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO visit_header" + " VALUES ('"+visitnumber+"','"+date+"','"+cookie+"','"+ip+"')");
```